# OK to use NSFetchedResultsController in separate thread to load TableViewCells?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

basically I'm trying to load a `UITableView` full of `CoreData` entities. I'd like to set the batch size of the `NSFetchedResultsController` to 0, and then load each object on each cell on a `GCD` thread using:

```
[_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Is this thread safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, neither your fetched results controller nor the table view are thread safe.

If I remember correctly you CAN do Core Data from a background thread, but you need a separate NSManagedObjectContext for each thread from which you will access your data.

You cannot make UI changes (like loading table view contents) from a separate background thread under any circumstances. UIView objects are not thread safe, period.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I meant actually like to download an image that's going be a thumbnail in a UITableView on GCD, that will work as long as you're not touching UIKit. Just curious, but why is NSFetchedController so much better then just loading the data into an array? Do you happen to know?

Comment: NSFetchedResultsController is a Core Data controller object that mediates between a Core Data database and things like table views. Once you understand how to use Core Data, it makes it possible to do things like add search fields that filter your results automatically, sort table views by different columns simply by clicking on the headings, etc.